# oAuth class file is missing from library

Tags: php, oauth, download, yahoo

I am trying to develop Yahoo oAuth in PHP. I downloaded script from

[oauth examples](http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/oauth/trunk/examples/yahoo/). But when i am running request_token.php it giving me following error. I problem is i don't have oauth class.

**$o = new OAuth(OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY, OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET, OAUT** here an error is coming

**Fatal error: Class 'OAuth' not found**

Where can i download complete oauth library for PHP.

Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That example was taken from http://svn.php.net/viewvc/pecl/oauth/trunk/examples/yahoo/, which is a directory belonging to the [oauth PECL](http://pecl.php.net/package/oauth) extension, so I'd start looking there.

Comment: @Kill Sorry, what do you mean? Have you installed the extension?

Comment: i downloaded files from both the links you have given both directories having example files only. same error is coming..

Comment: @Kill It's a binary PECL extension that needs installation. Please read http://php.net/manual/en/install.pecl.php

Comment: Thank You .. i'll go through it. :)